# How do I merge image back after splitting into blocks

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, pytorch

I splitted an image into blocks with the code below

```
block = []
for x in range(0, 224,16):
    for y in range(0, 224,16):
        block.append(im[y:y+16, x:x+16])
np_block = np.array(block)
```

[image]

The image shape is `224,224,3` and each block is `16,16,3`. How do I combine these blocks together to form the complete image?.
When I reshaped it (`np_block.reshape(224, 224,3)`), I got the below image which is completely different from the real image

[image]

**Edit:**
This has been answered in the comment section as thus:

```
reshaped_img = np_block.reshape(14,14,16,16,3).transpose(0,3,1,2,4).reshape(14*16,14*16,3)
```

The resulting image is rotated and also flipped compared to the original image. Here is the original image

[image: original image]

And here is the resulting image from the provided method to merge the blocks together

[image: merged image]

Doing `restored_img = np.flip(np.rot90(reshaped_img, k=1, axes=(0, 1)), axis=0)` will correctly restore the resulting image to its original form.

However, converting `restored_img` into a tensor in pytorch, `tensor_img = torch.from_numpy(restored_img)`throws the following error:

```
ValueError: At least one stride in the given numpy array is negative, and tensors with negative strides are not currently supported. (You can probably work around this by making a copy of your array  with array.copy().)
```

I worked around this as suggested in the error message.

`tensor_img = torch.from_numpy(restored_img.copy())` got rid of the error but the transformations (rotation and flipping) made on `restored_img` is not preserved. `tensor_img` stil remains the same as the last image above.

I noticed that the splitted blocks are not appended in the correct order when splitting the original image. This is evident in `np_block` when I visualized it (***the first image above looks flipped and rotated***). So, I changed the line `block.append(im[y:y+16, x:x+16])` to `block.append(im[x:x+16, y:y+16])`

Revisualizing `np_block` consequently gives the following  image

[image]

This seem closer to the original image and the blocks also looks like they are in the correct order (this is what I've observed). But the blocks do not overlap with each other.

How do I work around this, please?

Comment: np_block.reshape(14,14,16,16,3).transpose(0,3,1,2,4).reshape(14*16,14*16,3)

Comment: Works for me but had the image rotated 90-degrees to the right. So I did `np.rot90(kk, k=3, axes=(0, 1))` to rotate it back and got the exact image. Many thanks

Comment: @UlisesBussi, I updated the question, could you please take a look?

Comment: there the solution check it out and tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there the problem with original solution proposed is that you have to rearange the blocks `0,3` and `1,2` if you swap those dimensions then it will be solved. check:

```
block = [] #create blocks
for x in range(0, 224,16):
    for y in range(0, 224,16):
        block.append(im[y:y+16, x:x+16])
np_block = np.array(block)

reshaped_img = np_block.reshape(14,14,16,16,3).transpose(1,2,0,3,4).reshape(14*16,14*16,3)
#check indices are now (1,2,0,3,4) instead of (0,3,1,2,4) 

plt.imshow(np.hstack([im,reshaped_img]))
```

---

**Edit**

also from original comment this is just transpose output dimensions
`reshaped_img.transpose(1,0)`, but if you can correct in the original reshape it's a better solution

---

**Edit 2**

using the corrected stacking (with x in first dimension) the code would be:

```
block = []
for x in range(0, 224,16):
    for y in range(0, 224,16):
        block.append(im[x:x+16, y:y+16])
np_block = np.array(block)

reshaped_img = np_block.reshape(14,14,16,16,3).transpose(0,2,1,3,4).reshape(14*16,14*16,3)
```

Here makes morse sence: the first dimension of reshape in block (dim 0) with the first dimension of the subblock (dim 2), are grouped, then the same for the seccond dimensions of the block and and subblock (1,3).

In any case you can check the good solution by:

```
plt.imshow(np.hstack([im,reshaped_img]))
```

---

**Edit 3**
Last edit, here a code to check the original block reshape (with code of edit 2). Here you can see every block has some sense of getting a cut in the image:

```
b = np_block.reshape(14,14,16,16,3)
plt.figure()
for i in range(14):
    for j in range(14):
        plt.subplot(14,14,14*i+j+1)
        plt.imshow(b[i,j])
        plt.axis('off')
```

Comment: You are the best. Thank you. `reshaped_img`  now looks exactly like the original image but`tensor_img = torch.from_numpy(reshaped_img)` is still rotated. I guess this is an issue with `pytorch`.

Comment: So, I figured it out. pytorch's [transforms](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToTensor.html) did it.

`import torchvision.transforms as T` ,
`transform = T.ToTensor()`,
`tensor_img = transform(reshaped_img).unsqueeze(0)`.

I don't know exactly why `tensor_img = torch.from_numpy(reshaped_img)` didn't do the work. Thanks for your valuable contribution

Comment: I think that `pytorch.tensor` expect the dimensions in other order ( not sure but maybe something like `C x X x Y` channels width height ). The image rotated and mirrored is a transposition of axis x and y